# Creating a List of BufferedReaders

Tags: java, stream, io

I would like to have a method that would return a list of `BufferedReader` objects (for example for all files in a directory):

```
private List<BufferedReader> getInputReaders(List<String> filenames) {
    List<BufferedReader> result = new ArrayList<BufferedReader>();
    for(String filename : filenames)
        result.add(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filename), "UTF-8")));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Will this be a major waste of resources?

Will all those streams be opened at the moment of creation and remain so therefore holding system resources?

If yes, can I create those readers in "passive" mode without actually opening streams, or is there any other workaround (so I can build a List with thousands of readers safely)?

Comment: Why don't you just create the reader(s) when you need them?

Comment: @Kevin I simplified the task, I will need to deal with filenames mixed with urls mixed with directories with filename filters etc. I would like to hide all this in a separated method and have just a list of readers at the end.

Comment: Can you "hide" the mixed url in a class and give that to a factory or some other class that returns an appropriate reader instance?

Comment: @Kevin I can, but I would like to see if I can get away with a list of readers first, as it would be a simpler solution for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the constructor for `FileInputStream` invokes `open()` in its constructor. `open()` is a native method, which will most likely reserve a file descriptor for the file.

Instead of immediately returning a list of BufferedReaders, why not return a list of something that will open the underlying stream as needed? You can create a class that holds onto a filename and simply open the resource when called.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure it's a bad idea. You risk to consume all the available file descriptors, and there is no point in opening a reader to a file if you don't want to read from it.

If you want to read from the file, then open a reader, read from the file, and close the reader. Then, do the same for the next file to read from.

If you want a unique abstraction to read from various sources (URLs, files, etc.), then create your own `Source` interface, and multiple implementations which would wrap the resource to read from (URLSource, FileSource, etc.). Only open the actual reader on the wrapped resource when reading from your `Source` instance.

Answer (score 1):

yes those streams will be opened as soon as they are created

good way to avoid this is to create a LazyReader class that only initializes the Reader on first read

```
public class LazyReader extends Reader{

    String fileName;
    Reader reader=null;
    public LazyReader(String filename){
        super();
        this.fileName=fileName;
    }

    private void init(){
       if(reader==null)
           reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filename), "UTF-8"));
    }

    public int read(char[] cbuf, int off, int len){
        init();
        return reader.read(cbuff, off,len);
    }

    public int close(){
        init();
        reader.close();
    }

    //if you want marking you should also implement mark(int), reset() and markSupported()

}
```